# HW (video decode driver) is overloaded

Tags: android, decoder

I am getting an error "**call on stream failed HW is overloaded**" while using video decoder module.

I have also observed this is because of msm_vidc (video decoder driver) on Nexus 6P being overloaded.

How to get rid of this problem?

How to change the configuration settings to get rid of this?